# How to block fire?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fire

[image]

As you can see in the above image, I'm making a fire ghost (in Cycles). I can setup the flames, however, I have two issues:

(1) How do I make the flames stick close to the surface but not lose it's fast, fluttering nature?

(2) How do I enable a separate mesh object to block the fire? (I want the fire to rise out from the top and eye holes but not pass through the mesh completely).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select head and use smoke symulation then chose "Collision" (its on your screenshoot